# Send Action to button who is listening for it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, keylistener

I have a JButton that has action listener.

```
btn_.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

And I have a JSpinner that listens for key events.

```
spn_.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            System.out.println("Someone pressed enter key");
        }
    }
});
```

What I would like to do, is whenever user presses enter key while the spinner is selected, I would like it to execute whatever command the button does.
Yes I understand that I can simply have a function for the actions button does, and then execute the same function when user presses enter key. I am asking this because I am curious if it is possible for components in Swing to send actions to each other and how to do it rather than what is the correct way to program.

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes I understand that I can simply have a function for the actions button does, and then execute the same function when user presses enter key. I am asking this because I am curious if it is possible for components in Swing to send actions to each other and how to do it rather than what is the correct way to program.

If you are implying that executing a function is the correct way, I would suggest that is not the best way to solve the problem.

The correct way is to share the Action, not the method that you invoke.

You should NOT be using a KeyListener at all in this solution. The general solution is to use Key Bindings. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

However, in your case it is even a little easier because you can just share the ActionListener:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListner() {...}

JTextField editor = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
editor.addActionListener(al);
button.addActionListener(al);
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that `actionPerfomed` would be first called to `editor`, and than to the `button`?

Comment: These are two different components. The user would only ever have focus on the spinner or the button.

Comment: Yes I have read the question multiple times. The same ActionListener is invoked whether you click on the button or use the Enter key on the spinner. This is how you reuse code in Swing. Read the tutorial on Key Bindings to understand the concept better.

Comment: I wish I would have taken this matter so seriously while writing answer :). Your solution is perfect one ... +1

Answer (score 1):

Use [doClick()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29) method of JButton:

```
btn_.doClick()
```

Within `keyPressed` as following:

```
spn_.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            btn_.doClick()
        }
    }
});
```

The `doClick()` method as specified in oracle doc:

> Programmatically perform a "click". This does the same thing as if the
>   user had pressed and released the button.

Comment: Yes this works but it is NOT the way to solve the problem. The ActionListener should be shared. Don't use a KeyListener, that is not the way Swing was designed to work.

Comment: @camickr got it thanks. Would take care of thus next time while answering...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
spn_.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            btn_.doClick(); // fires the actionPerfomed on the button
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It answers the question, but is NOT the preferred approach to solving the problem.

Comment: I think, it IS actually :)

Comment: See Andrew's comment to the original question. We both took the time to comment even though an answer had been accepted because we are trying to encourage people to use Swing the way it was designed to be used.